# how to change data in range?

Tags: python, python-3.x

how to change data in range?

e.g: i have **N** number. if **x** mutiple of a, change **x** to *oke*. if **x** mutiple of b, change **x** to *nice*. if **x** mutiple of c, change **x** to *good*.

N : 12
A : 2
B : 3
C : 4

1 Oke Nice OkeGood 5 OkeNice 7 OkeGood Nice Oke 11 OkeGoodNice

that's my code

```
int_n = int(input('input N : '))
int_a = int(input('input A : '))
int_b = int(input('input B : '))
int_c = int(input('input C : '))

for i in range(1, int_n + 1) :
    if i / int_a == 0 :
        print('oke')
    if i / int_b == 0 :
        print('nice')
    if i / int_c == 0 :
        print('good')
    print()
```

i need help, thank you:))

Comment: What is the problem? What output do you expect to get?

Comment: N : 12
A : 2
B : 3
C : 4

1 Oke Nice OkeGood 5 OkeNice 7 OkeGood Nice Oke 11 OkeGoodNice

that's my expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
N = 12
A = 2
B = 3
C = 4

lst = []
for x in range(1, N+1):
    if x % A == 0:
        lst.append('Oke')
    elif x % B == 0:
        lst.append('Nice')
    elif x % C == 0:
        lst.append('Good')
    else:
        lst.append(x)

result = ' '.join([str(x) for x in lst])
print(result)
```

Output:

```
1 Oke Nice Oke 5 Oke 7 Oke Nice Oke 11 Oke
```